# Link Firebase Storage with Firebase Cloud Firestore Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to save pictures in firebase Storage. I need a way to link these pictures to a document in firestore database. Is there a simple way to do this?
For example if I upload a picture to storage I want to save a link or some path of that picture in firestore using which i can access the image later.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can get the download URL of a file that is uploaded to Cloud Storage and check the docs to see how you can [write that URL to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Answer (score 0):

Click Firebase-> Storage-> Upload and download a file with Firebase Storage option in Android Studio. After following the necessary steps, we expect it to download the relevant libraries. We need to get the last text connected and dependencies set up correctly. We do the same for Firebase Realtime Database and Authentication.
[image]